# Pandas : Problem with aggregation by periods of two months

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I want to aggregate data by periods of two months by using the groupby method of pandas. And I cannot achieve the exepected results. Indeed I have data that spans 4 months. Therefore I want two periods : the first one between 2018-06-01 and 2018-07-31 and the seconde one between 2018-08-01 and 2018-09-30. Below in the code, you will find the obtained and the expected results. Could you help me about this ? Thank you in advance !

```
# data sample
data={'A': pd.to_datetime(['2018-06-01','2018-06-15','2018-07-01','2018-07-15','2018-08-01','2018-08-15','2018-09-01','2018-09-15','2018-09-30']),
          'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

#create dataframe
test=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

#aggregation of data by period of two months
test.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='A', freq='2M',closed="right")).sum()

# The results

#              B
# A             
# 2018-06-30   2
# 2018-08-31   4
# 2018-10-31   3

#The expected results : 

#              B
# A             
# 2018-07-31  4
# 2018-09-30  5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it possible with your approach, because of how time frequencies are defined in pandas. The closest I could get was:

```
In [22]: test.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='A', freq='2M', closed='left', base="2018-06-01")).sum()                                                                                      
Out[22]: 
            B
A            
2018-07-31  4
2018-09-30  4
2018-11-30  1
```

A not-so-elegant way to get your results could be:

```
In [30]: test['year'] = [x.year for x in test.A]                                                                                                                                   

In [31]: test['month'] = [x.month for x in test.A]                                                                                                                                 

In [58]: bimestres = np.repeat(np.arange(1,13,2),2)                                                                                                                                

In [59]: test['bimestre'] = [bimestres[x] for x in test.month]                                                                                                                     

In [60]: test.groupby(by=['year', 'bimestre'])['B'].sum()                                                                                                                          
Out[60]: 
year  bimestre
2018  7           4
      9           5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks I will use your solution !